# typescript - access "root" module same name as actual submodule

Tags: typescript

I have two modules in TypeScript:

```
module superModule {
  export interface myInterface { /*...*/ }
}

module app.superModule {
  var x: superModule.myInterface;
}
```

Notice, that there are two different "superModule" modules. One in root, second as submodule of app module.

The code above is evaluated as there is missing "myInterface" interface, becouse compiler is searching only in app.superModule.

How to access "root" superModule from submodule superModule?

TypeScript playground: http://goo.gl/BdOJ1D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 'global' keyword or equivalent in TypeScript, but you can use `import` to create an alias for a type or variable:

```
module superModule {
  export interface myInterface { /*...*/ }
}

// Can be placed anywhere where the top definition
// of 'superModule' is visible
import superModule_myInterface = superModule.myInterface;
module app.superModule {
  var x: superModule_myInterface;
}
```